# Why does the command " ionic serve " in git bash gives an error?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run an ionic server through git bash on windows but its failing and showing an error

> Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. Are you in an Ionic project?

Comment: How did you create the project ? With `ionic start` CLI command ?

Comment: Yes , ionic start projectName

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the possible solutions

From a recent update just rename the `ionic.project` to `ionic.config.json`

and install bower since ionic requires bower using `npm i bower`

and see to it that you are running command in your project folder only